# PageRank algorithm for grid graph

Tags: algorithms, markov-chains, math-software, page-rank

I am currently studying the PageRank algorithm. To find the ranks i know you have two options:

- Compute the result of a large linear system
- Apply the surfer concept (like Markov chains)

I have this graph below, is a grid composed of 3x3 nodes. The central node has more connections so I guess it will have more rank than the others, the nodes 2,4,6,8 have 3 incomming connections and the others have incomming degree 2.
[image]

Can I assume that the nodes 1,3,7,9 have the same pageRank values? Also for 2,4,6,8?
What is the best way to compute the PageRank for this graph?
Thanks, very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to symmetry, you know that $2,4,6,8$ will have the same rank (call it $r_s$, as in *side*), and $1,3, 7,9$ will also have the same rank (call it $r_c$, as in *corner*). The central node has its own rank, call it $r_0$

Now, look at the equations that $r_s$ must satisfy. Since $r_s=r_2$, you can look at the equation for $r_2$, and it is $r_2 = \frac14 r_0 + \frac12 r_1 + \frac12 r_3$ which translates in our new variables into 
$$r_s = \frac14 r_0 + \frac12 r_c + \frac12 r_c$$

---

Next, the equation for $r_1$ is $r_1 = \frac{1}{3}r_2 + \frac13 r_4$ which translates into

$$r_c = \frac13 r_s + \frac13 r_s$$

---

Finally, the equation for $r_0$ translates from $r_0=\frac13 r_2 + \frac13 r_4 + \frac13 r_6 + \frac13 r_8$ into
$$r_0=\frac13 r_s + \frac13 r_s + \frac13 r_s + \frac13 r_s$$

---

Simplifying, you now have a system of $3$ equations with $3$ variables:

$$r_s = \frac14 r_0 + r_c\\
r_c = \frac23 r_s\\
r_0 = \frac43 r_s$$

which shoudln't be hard to solve at all.